# r - Aggregate combine with foreach

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach

Instead of using rbind or cbind to combine results from foreach, I'd like to instead return an aggregate of the results using colMeans.

The context is I'm trying to use k-fold cv to tune lambda for fitting a lasso model from a package that doesn't have cv. For example, I'm getting results that look something like this:

```
library(foreach)
lambda_vector <- 2:1
foreach(i = 1:length(lambda_vector), .combine = 'rbind') %:%
          foreach(j= 1:5, .combine = 'rbind') %do% {
            t <- c(lambda_vector[i], rnorm(3, mean = 0.7, .1))
            names(t) <- c("Lambda", "Accuracy", "Sensitivity", "Specificity")
            t
          }


         Lambda  Accuracy Sensitivity Specificity
result.1      2 0.8107573   0.6166583   0.5846272
result.2      2 0.7233763   0.7831056   0.8735858
result.3      2 0.7168183   0.8373519   0.8426220
result.4      2 0.8941758   0.7251262   0.9247312
result.5      2 0.6129619   0.7698698   0.6448826
result.1      1 0.6203058   0.6714010   0.6400115
result.2      1 0.6080379   0.7946973   0.6324187
result.3      1 0.6727701   0.6753794   0.8079118
result.4      1 0.6983270   0.7755013   0.8466028
result.5      1 0.5417440   0.7964172   0.7894349
```

Is it possible to aggregate the results from the inner loop? Or is this best handled after running the loop? That is, I'd like output to look like this:

```
  Group.1  Accuracy Sensitivity Specificity
1       1 0.6282370   0.7426793   0.7432759
2       2 0.7516179   0.7464224   0.7740898
```

I had tried replacing the inner combine function with something like

```
take_mean <- function(...){
  t1 <- rbind(...)
  colMeans(t1)
}
```

but the results aren't correct.

Comment: It is often simpler to return a list of lists (i.e. without using `.combine`), and shape the results later.

Comment: I think I've come to realize that. I'm not sure why I was so stuck up on aggregating it inside the loop.